# Session variables not set on header redirect

Tags: php, session, variables, header

I'm having a problem where my session variables aren't getting set/saved.

Here is my code:

index.php has:

```
<? //this is first line of page
session_start(); 
?>
<form action="admin_process_login.php" method="post">
<p>EMAIL</p><input name="email" type="text">
<p>PASSWORD</p><input name="password" type="password" />
<input type="submit" value="Enter">
</form>
```

admin_process_login.php

```
<? //this is first line of page
session_start(); 
$useremail = $_POST['email'];
$postpassword = $_POST['password'];
include('admin_config.php');

if ($postpassword != "" && $useremail != "") {
//Connect to database
mysql_connect("localhost", $dbusr, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("studioel_dental") or die(mysql_error());

//Look for a matching email/password
$query = "SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE users.email = '$useremail'
    AND users.password = '$postpassword'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0){
    header("Location: http://www.dentalbenefitprogram.com/admin.php?error=nomatch");
    } else {
    //set session variables and load supplies page
        $uid = $row['id'];
        $unamex = $row['name'];
        $uemailx = $row['email'];
        $utypex = $row['type'];

        $_SESSION['userid']=$uid;
        $_SESSION['uname']=$unamex;
        $_SESSION['uemail']=$uemailx;
        $_SESSION['utype']=$utypex;

        header("Location: http://www.dentalbenefitprogram.com/admin_groups.php");
        exit;
        };
} else {
//email or password fields were blank. Return to login page
header("Location: http://www.dentalbenefitprogram.com/admin.php?error=blank");
};
?>
```

You can probably guess: the session variables aren't being set...

Any help is appreciated greatly!

Comment: This normally works, please create a test script only initializing a session, setting a session variable and doing a redirect. Test if it works (or not), if it does not work, replace your code here, as it contains much more than you're asking about. If it works, please rephrase your question.

Comment: Oops. I'm an idiot.

Let me withdraw my question. Thanks for the help finding it though, Hakre.

I forgot to make a while loop after getting my results from the database.

Sorry (feeling sheepish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brian:

My guess is that before your comment in the first line you have a space that is causing this problem.

PHP manual cautions users to watch out for this:

> Note:
>   To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

Also, you may want to consider using long tags instead of short tags.

Best

Answer (score 0):

use `ob_start();` at the extreme beginning of ur code
& dont forget to add `ob_end_flush();` at the extreme end of ur code